# JqGrid Checkbox enable/disable via function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jqgrid

I wanna be able to disable/enable a jqGrid checkbox based on a bool value passed back from a function. How would I do this?

*snippet of code below*

```
 colModel: [
    { name: 'IsSystemAdmin', index: 'IsSystemAdmin', width: 50, align: "center", 
    formatter: "checkbox", 
    formatoptions: { disabled: isSystemAdmin}, editable: true }
],
```

****Please note  where I call the  function:
 formatoptions: { disabled: isSystemAdmin}, editable: true }****

---

```
var isSystemAdmin = new function(){
   //do something and return a bool value
}
```

---

or

```
function isSystemAdmin(){
  //do something and return a bool value
}
```

---

Resolved  apparently the code I have above does in fact work. 
Only Change :

**formatoptions: { disabled: isSystemAdmin()}**

instead of

**formatoptions: { disabled: isSystemAdmin}**

Answer (score 0):

Use the .jqGrid('setSelection' method

```
function isSystemAdmin() { 
  jQuery("#list13").jqGrid('setSelection',"13"); 
});
```

Comment: In my case is "#list13" suppose to be the id of the row?

Comment: #list13 is the id of your jdGrid, the first argument is the method name, the second argument is the row index you want to check/uncheck